# Raspberry Pi with gertduino to use the rtc

Tags: rtc, gertboard

I just setup my raspberry pi with the gertduino and I tried the given blink example. It works fine and now I wanted to use the rtc from the gertduino to set the time from the raspberry. How ever I installed i2c-tools and when I use i2cdetect the table shows 2 entries both UU in 20b and 30b.
Now I just wanted to use the command:

```
sudo hwclock -r
```

and the response is:

> hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
>
> hwclock: Use the --debug option to see the details of our search for an access method

I would be really happy if anyone could give me some suggestions or maybe someone had the same problem configuring the rtc.
Cheers Max

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the answer. It was a mistake in the setup file.